# Subtract seconds from date pymongo aggregation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

This is my python code:

```
date1=datetime.datetime(2016,2,3)
cursor = collection.aggregate([
 {"$match":{"EndTime":{"$gte":date1}}},
 {"$project": { "EndTime":"$EndTime","StartTime":{ "$subtract": [ "$EndTime", "$TimeSpent"*1000]},"TimeSpent":"$TimeSpent"}},
 {"$sort":{"StartTime":1}}
])
```

All my StartTime fields are None. How should I get the StartTime field as my python output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipeline should use the available [arithmetic operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/) to do the computation; you are supposedly "multiplying" a string literal instead of using the **[`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/)** operator hence why you are getting a null result, mongo
does not recognise this part `"$TimeSpent"*1000` in `{ "$subtract": [ "$EndTime", "$TimeSpent"*1000] }`.

Change your pipeline to use the **[`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/)** operator within an expression instead and :

```
date1=datetime.datetime(2016,2,3)
cursor = collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "EndTime": { "$gte": date1 } } },
    {
        "$project": { 
            "EndTime": 1,           
            "TimeSpent": 1,
            "StartTime": { 
                "$subtract": [ 
                    "$EndTime", 
                    { "$multiply": ["$TimeSpent", 1000] } 
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "StartTime": 1 } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked but it's not the same on here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/ I used this example.

Comment: It is the same, the difference is the above uses an expression which is a valid argument for the [**`$subtract`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) operator.

Comment: Ya. I saw that, the mutiply operator.